# Why does my benchmark for memory usage in Node.js seem wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I wanted to test memory usage for objects in node.js. My approach was simple: I first use `process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024` to get the baseline memory. And I have an array of sizes, i.e. the number of entries in objects `const WIDTHS = [100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000]` and I plan to loop through it and create objects of that size and compare the current memory usage with the baseline memory.

```js
function memoryUsed() {
    const mbUsed = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024 
    return mbUsed
}


function createObject(size) {
  const obj = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    obj[Math.random()] = i;
  }

  return obj;
}

const SIZES = [100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000, 1000000]

const memoryUsage = {}

function fn() {
  SIZES.forEach(size => {
  const before = memoryUsed()
  const obj = createObject(size)
  const after = memoryUsed()
  const diff = after - before
  memoryUsage[size] = diff
})
}

fn()
```

but the results didn't look correct:

```
{
  '100': 0.58087158203125,
  '500': 0.0586700439453125,
  '1000': 0.15680694580078125,
  '5000': 0.7640304565429688,
  '10000': 0.30365753173828125,
  '50000': 7.4157257080078125,
  '100000': 0.8076553344726562,
}
```

It doesn't make sense. Also, since the object `memoryUsage`  that records the memory usage itself takes up more memory as it grows so I think it adds some overhead.

What are some of the more robust and proper ways to benchmark memory usage in node.js?

Comment: This is very silly! Blocking the process with calculations and trying to get some data by that same process.

Comment: @DiD yea I knwo this is probably really naive that's why I posted this question. do you mind writing up an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing missing controlling for the garbage collector kicking in at "random" times. To attribute used memory to specific actions performed, you need to manually trigger full GC runs before taking a measurement. Concretely, modify `memoryUsed` so it reads:

```
function memoryUsed() {
  gc();
  const mbUsed = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
  return mbUsed;
}
```

and run the test in Node with `--expose-gc`. Then you'll get reasonable numbers:

```
{
  '100': 0.20072174072265625,
  '500': 0.0426025390625,
  '1000': 0.08499908447265625,
  '5000': 0.37823486328125,
  '10000': 0.7519683837890625,
  '50000': 4.9071807861328125,
  '100000': 9.80963134765625,
  '500000': 43.04571533203125,
  '1000000': 86.08901977539062
}
```

The first result (for `100`) is obviously too high; not sure why (and if I repeat the test for `100` at the end, its result is in line with the others). The other numbers check out: for a 2x or 5x increase in the number of properties, memory consumption increases by approximately the same 2x or 5x.

---

My high-level comment is that I'm not sure what you're trying to measure here. The majority of memory used in this scenario is spent on strings of the form `"0.38459934255705686"`, whereas your description seems to indicate that you're more interested in objects.
The marginal cost of one object property depends on the state of the object: when several objects share a shape/"hidden class", then each property in an object takes just one pointer (4 bytes in browsers [32-bit platforms, or pointer compression], 8 bytes in Node [64-bit without pointer compression]). When an object is in dictionary mode, each additional property will take about 6 pointers on average (depending on when the dictionary's backing store needs to be grown), so 24 or 48 bytes depending on pointer size. (The latter is the scenario that this test is creating.)
In both cases, this is just the additional size of the object holding the property; the property's name and value might of course need additional memory.

Comment: thanks so much for the comments! actually I was trying to measure the memory usage differences between Map and object of the same size. And my findings are that most of the times objects are more memory efficient than maps. but when the keys are numeric string, sometimes objects end up using more memory. The way I tested was to take heap snapshots. Would love it if you can answer these two questions: 1. is it true that most of the times objects use less memory that maps of the same size? 2. when it comes to measure memory usage, should I take heap snapshots or use process.memoryUsage in node?

Comment: @Joji Re (1) No, Maps use less memory (as your own test easily shows). One reason is that Maps don't have to store writable/enumerable/configurable bits for each property. Re (2), you can use whichever you find more convenient, they both have pros and cons. `process.memoryUsage` doesn't provide detailed insight, so you don't know what you're measuring, but it avoids the danger of overlooking something relevant. Heap snapshots can be inspected in detail, so they help you understand what's happening, but can't be automated as easily.

Comment: I tested Map using the same script it does seem like in most cases Map is using less memory (although not always) but I remember taking heap headshot in browser I found `Map` is using 20 - 30% more memory according to the RetainedSize... another related question if you don't mind, I saw Map is consistently faster than object for insertion at runtime, is there a brief explanation behind this performance difference? What optimization V8 has done that's specific to map?

Comment: @Joji there's no brief explanation. Maps are optimized for adding and removing entries. Objects are (largely) optimized for having a fixed set of properties. The recommendation is to use Maps when that semantically makes sense.

Comment: got it thanks. yea that's my understanding as well. about memory usage benchmarks, sometimes the `diff` number can be negative. that means `after` is even bigger than `after`. I did add `gc();` in `memoryUsed` . do you know why that might have caused that?

Comment: Apparently the garbage collector was able to free some other objects.